# MongoDB Kafka connect ChangeStreamHandler do not support truncatedArrays

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-kafka-connector

I am using ChangeStreamHandler in mongo Kafka sink connector to stream changes from mongo source to sink collection

```
"change.data.capture.handler": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.ChangeStreamHandler"
```

On updates events from the source MongoDB collection the change stream handler is failing with exception

```
 ERROR Unable to process record SinkRecord{kafkaOffset=3, timestampType=CreateTime} ConnectRecord{topic='quickstart.sampleData', kafkaPartition=0, key={"_id": {"_data": "8262A5CD4B000000012B022C0100296E5A1004B80560BF7F114B04962A5F523CEAB5D046645F6964006462A5CC9B84956FD488691BF10004"}}, keySchema=Schema{STRING}, value={"_id": {"_data": "8262A5CD4B000000012B022C0100296E5A1004B80560BF7F114B04962A5F523CEAB5D046645F6964006462A5CC9B84956FD488691BF10004"}, "operationType": "update", "clusterTime": {"$timestamp": {"t": 1655033163, "i": 1}}, "ns": {"db": "quickstart", "coll": "sampleData"}, "documentKey": {"_id": {"$oid": "62a5cc9b84956fd488691bf1"}}, "updateDescription": {"updatedFields": {"hello": "moto"}, "removedFields": [], "truncatedArrays": []}}, valueSchema=Schema{STRING}, timestamp=1655033166742, headers=ConnectHeaders(headers=)} (com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData)
org.apache.kafka.connect.errors.DataException: Warning unexpected field(s) in updateDescription [truncatedArrays]. {"updatedFields": {"hello": "moto"}, "removedFields": [], "truncatedArrays": []}. Cannot process due to risk of data loss.
at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.operations.OperationHelper.getUpdateDocument(OperationHelper.java:99)
at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.operations.Update.perform(Update.java:57)
at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.ChangeStreamHandler.handle(ChangeStreamHandler.java:84)
at com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.lambda$buildWriteModelCDC$3(MongoProcessedSinkRecordData.java:99)
at java.base/java.util.Optional.flatMap(Optional.java:294)
```

Below is the Change stream event received on the sink side

```
{"schema":{"type":"string","optional":false},"payload":"{\"_id\": {\"_data\": \"8262A5CD4B000000012B022C0100296E5A1004B80560BF7F114B04962A5F523CEAB5D046645F6964006462A5CC9B84956FD488691BF10004\"}, \"operationType\": \"update\", \"clusterTime\": {\"$timestamp\": {\"t\": 1655033163, \"i\": 1}}, \"ns\": {\"db\": \"quickstart\", \"coll\": \"sampleData\"}, \"documentKey\": {\"_id\": {\"$oid\": \"62a5cc9b84956fd488691bf1\"}}, \"updateDescription\": {\"updatedFields\": {\"hello\": \"moto\"}, \"removedFields\": [], \"truncatedArrays\": []}}"}
```

On looking at the  code in class

```
com.mongodb.kafka.connect.sink.cdc.mongodb.operations.OperationHelper.getUpdateDocument(OperationHelper.java:99)
```

It shows that the updateDescription.updatedfields only handles updatedFields & removedFields.. support for truncatedArrays is not present.
Is this a bug? or I need to tune my source connector to somehow stop sending truncatedArrays in changeEvents.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue here and i could solve that setting up the following configuration at the **Source Connector**:

**"change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup"**

A Full Exemple:

```
{
  "name": "mongo-simple-source",
  "config": {
    "connector.class": "com.mongodb.kafka.connect.MongoSourceConnector",
    "connection.uri": "yourMongodbUri",
    "database": "yourDataBase",
    "collection": "yourCollection",
    "change.stream.full.document": "updateLookup"
  }
}
```